# A Ruby method for resolving relative paths while keeping absolute paths?

Tags: ruby, cross-platform

I am working on writing a rake build scrip which will work cross platform ( Mac OSX, Linux , Windows ). The build script will be consumed by a  [CI server](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/cruise-release-management).

I want the logic of my script to be as follows:

1. If the path is determined to be relative, make it absolute by making *output_path = FOO_HOME + user_supplied_relative_path*
2. If the path is determined to be absolute, take it as-is

I'm currently using *Pathname.new(location).absolute?* but it's not working correctly on windows.

What approach would you suggest for this?

Comment: The title of your question is somewhat misleading. It does not really correspond to what your asking for in the text.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504646/ruby-opening-files-relative-to-home-directory

Answer (score 34):

```
require 'pathname'
(Pathname.new "/foo").absolute? # => true
(Pathname.new "foo").absolute? # => false
```

Comment: require 'pathname' is part of the ruby standard library

Answer (score 9):

The method you're looking for is [realpath.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Pathname.html#M001710)

Essentially you do this:

```
absolute_path = Pathname.new(path).realpath
```

N.B.: The Pathname module states that usage is experimental on machines that do not have unix like pathnames. So it's implementation dependent. Looks like JRuby should work on Windows.

Comment: `Pathname#realpath` assumes your relative path is relative to the current working directory, which might not be the users home.

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in function that covers both cases and does exactly what you want:

```
output_path = File.absolute_path(user_supplied_path, FOO_HOME)
```

The trick is supplying a second argument. It servers as a base directory if (and only if) the first argument is a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

`Pathname` can do all that for you

```
require "pathname"
home= Pathname.new("/home/foo")

home + Pathname.new("/bin") # => #<Pathname:/bin>
home + Pathname.new("documents") # => #<Pathname:/home/foo/documents>
```

I am not sure about this on windows though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `File.expand_path` if the relative directory is relative to the current working directory.

I checked on Linux and windows and didn't have any issues.

Assuming `FOO_HOME` is the working directory, the code would be:

```
output_path = File.expand_path user_supplied_relative_path
```

Comment: `File.expand_path` does the following: 1. if the argument is a relative path, make a absolute path out of it; 2. expand  `~` and `~username`. This means, `File.expand_path` does a little more than the OP asked for. Use `File.absolute_path` instead.

Comment: You do not have to _assume_ that `FOO_HOME` is the working directory.  `File.chdir` with a block ensures that without modifying your working directory permanently: `File.chdir(FOO_HOME){File.absolute_path user_supplied_relative_path}`. An even simpler way is to supply  `FOO_HOME` as a second argument to the call. Both `File.expand_path` and `File.absolute_path` accept it.