# How to open files relative to home directory

Tags: ruby

The following fails with `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`, even if the file exists:

```
open('~/some_file')
```

However, I can do this:

```
open(File.expand_path('~/some_file'))
```

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't `open` process the tilde as pointing to the home directory?
2. Is there a slicker way than `File.expand_path`?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

1. The shell (bash, zsh, etc) is responsible for wildcard expansion, so in your first example there's no shell, hence no expansion. Using the tilde to point to `$HOME` is a mere convention; indeed, if you look at the documentation for `File.expand_path`, it correctly interprets the tilde, but it's a feature of the function itself, not something inherent to the underlying system; also, `File.expand_path` requires the `$HOME` environment variable to be correctly set. Which bring us to the possible alternative...
2. Try this:

   ```
   open(ENV['HOME']+'/some_file')
   ```

I hope it's slick enough. I personally think using an environment variable is semantically clearer than using `expand_path`.

Comment: using windows.. had to do `open(ENV['HOME']+'some_file')`

Comment: Use simply `File.join(ENV['HOME'], '/some_file')` to have it work in both cases.

Answer (score 138):

Not sure if this was available before Ruby 1.9.3 but I find that the most elegant solution is to use `Dir.home` which is part of core.

```
open("#{Dir.home}/some_file")
```

Comment: Nope, not available to users below 1.9.3 (http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_2_180/Dir/home/class).

Answer (score 14):

Instead of relying on the `$HOME` environment variable being set correctly, which could be a hassle when you use shared network computers for development,  you could get this from Ruby using:

```
require 'etc'
open ("#{Etc.getpwuid.dir}/some_file")
```

I believe this identifies the current logged-in user and gets their home directory rather than relying on the global `$HOME` environment variable being set. This is an alternative solution to the above I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the tilde problem, and a patch was created to add `absolute_path`
which treats tilde as an ordinary character.

From the File documentation:

```
absolute_path(file_name [, dir_string] ) → abs_file_name
```

> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point. If the given pathname starts with a “~” it is NOT expanded, it is treated as a normal directory name.